# I am playing with canvas. How do I get it to work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my html:

```
<canvas id="test" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

here is my javascript:

```
var canvas_one = document.getElementById("test");
var canvas_context = canvas_one.getContext("2d");
canvas_context.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
```

I am just experimenting with this and none of the tutorials seem to be working. I am using chrome as my browser fyi.

The original typo was only on here; not in my editor. Sorry about that.

I am getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null even with the jsfiddle example.

Ok I figured out what was wrong. Because my javascript was in the head of the html file, it was being loaded before the DOM was completely loaded, So when it tried to do `var canvas_one = document.getElementById("test");` it set canvas_one to null. So what I did is just wrap it in jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var canvas_one = document.getElementById("test");
var canvas_context = canvas_one.getContext("2d");

canvas_context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
canvas_context.fillRect(10, 25, 150, 100);

});
```

Now it waits for the DOM to load before it reads the javascript and everything works.

Comment: You need to let us know what erros are you getting. In chrome press `ctrl+shift+i` and in the bottom right corner you should see a litter red icon, click it. But without that i think firstly you have an issue with `document.getElemById` it should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: oops that was a typo. I don't have my code like that in my editor though.

Comment: Here is the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null

Comment: Working fine here.. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure any code which references the DOM executes only after the DOM is ready. This can be achieved by wrapping everything in a function which is called using window.onload, or by using jQuery or a similar library to do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

The [mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial) is the best one in my opinion, try it.

Correct the following: **document.getElementById**, you just typed it wrong.

Comment: In order to avoid using a framework just to wait the page loads and then retrieve the element, you can optionally put your script anywhere after the canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo for `getElementById`, also I suggest setting a `fillStyle` as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9KHYC/)**

```
var canvas_one = document.getElementById("test");
var canvas_context = canvas_one.getContext("2d");

canvas_context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
canvas_context.fillRect(10, 25, 150, 100);
```

Comment: This seems to be working great in jsfiddle, just not in my browser. Not sure why.

Comment: It may be that your canvas element is not ready in the DOM, and therefore returns undefined when you try to call it.

Comment: that's exactly what was happening.